# How to make bash scripts to automatically add and download files from github?

Tags: linux, bash, git

I have a cloned directory on a linux server. Keyed access is configured. After some processing on the server, at the output, I get csv files that I need to add to the git. I also need to receive files on the server that have been changed on the git itself (these can be either new added files, or some changes in the code). The adding process happens every day, so I want to automate it. On one of the sites I found an example suitable for me. Two scripts that add and clone changes to the server. Startup automation takes place through crontab.

Code file:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Go to the GIT category
cd '/home/user/www/'

# Submitting changes to the main branch
git checkout main
git add -A
git commit -m "update main"
git push
```

and...

```
#!/bin/bash
# Go to the GIT category
cd '/home/user/www/'

# Loading data from the main branch
git checkout main
git pull
```

But I get the following errors in the output, what could be the problem?

Cronlog:

```
/home/user/RFFI-V/Work/start_git_download.sh: line 3: cd: too many arguments
/home/user/RFFI-V/Work/start_git_push.sh: line 3: cd: too many arguments
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)
Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).
```

Comment: What if you just run the `cd '/home/user/www/'` command on the target machine? (As root, as crontab runs as root...)

Comment: The error message `cd: too many arguments` doesn't seem to match your scripts as shown in the question. Did you copy&paste the code you are actually using? For debugging change the first line to `#!/bin/bash -x` and check the resulting output in the log.

Comment: is git init misssing or you are cloningthis directory?

Comment: As shown, I'd say these should work. I have to say this stinks of Windows-style newlines. Any chance your scripts are CRLF? If so, bash is not compatible with that, convert to Unix-style LF.

Comment: Don't do this.  Using git to store content that is not human generated is really not a good idea, no matter how common it may be.

Answer (score 0):

Run each command manually, to see if you receive any issues.

If you dont receive any issues, then is the bash script in the correct folder for crontab and the script by default would run as root, if you want to run the script as a different user, an example syntax to setup the script to run as a different user in crontab is shown below,

`1 2 3 4 5 USERNAME /path/to/script.sh`